# Why does using long int in multiplication generate a strange number?

Tags: c

After compiling this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    long int a = 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
    printf("%i\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

I get `-1486618624` as a result. How can I make this code work?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: The largest number a long int can hold is 2147483647.

Comment: A regular int would have given you the same problem.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid depends if you are on a 32 bit or 64 bit platform. If on a 32 bit platform, no doubt OP wants `long long int` and `%lld`.

Comment: long int would most probably be 32 bits. If you want 64 bits, use long long int or long long. Also, use 1000LL. Non-suffixed literals will be of type int, which results in an int multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instances of `1000` you have specified are `int`s, therefore the multiplication takes place by multiplying `int`s and getting an `int`. This is overflowing before it gets assigned to a `long int`. Try:

```
long int a = 1000L * 1000L * 1000L * 1000L * 1000L * 1000L;
```

Also you need to then print the answer using a `long int` format, e.g.:

```
printf("%ld\n", a);
```

Note a `long int` may also be too small (if you are on some 32 bit platforms the maximum storable in a `long int` is `2^31 - 1`, whereas on 64 bit platforms it's `2^63 - 1` which is sufficient), in which case try:

```
long long int a = 1000LL * 1000LL * 1000LL * 1000LL * 1000LL * 1000LL;
printf("%lld\n", a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are assigning to a `long int`, each of your `1000`s is an `int`, so the computer tries to calculate the result as an `int`. A number that exceeds the maximum `int` size overflows, causing it to "wrap around" and be seen as negative, because one bit of the memory used for an `int` is a negative flag.

You need to cast the `1000`s, either with `1000L` or `(long int) 1000` for each. You also need `%ld` instead of `%i` in your `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
long long var=1000LL*1000LL*1000LL;  // append LL

printf("%lld",var);
```